# Accessibility test case using axe core and webdriverjs - Error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser, axe

I have an automated WebUI tesing case which is supposed to test a website on accessibility. It's working fine and giving me the required output locally on my Mac but unfortunately failing on my VM (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS).

This is the source code:

```
    const AxeBuilder = require('@axe-core/webdriverjs');
    const { Builder, By, Key, promise, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');
    const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
    promise.USE_PROMISE_MANAGER = false;
    const options = new firefox.Options();
    options.headless();
    const driver = new Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .setFirefoxOptions(options)
        .build();
    
    async function main() {
        await driver.get('https://digital.hamburg.de/').then(() => {
        new AxeBuilder(driver).analyze(async (err, results) => {
            try {
                console.log(results.violations);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("Something went wrong", e.message);
            } finally {
                await driver.close()
            }
    
        });
    
    });
    }
    
    main();
```

And the following my output which I'm getting from the VM:

```
(node:38796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Server terminated early with status 2
    at /home/jenkins/workspace/test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:248:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:38796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:38796) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:38796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Server terminated early with status 2
    at /home/jenkins/workspace/test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:248:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:38796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
```

I'm quite a newbie at this and glad for any help.

Comment: I think the issue might be that you return `AxeBuilder(driver).analyze()`, which is not a promise (since you used it by passing a callback function). So when the `await` for the `driver.get` call doesn't resolve, it might throw an unhandled promise rejection.

I think you can fix it by changing the call to analyze to use the promise version ([by not passing a callback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@axe-core/webdriverjs#user-content-axebuilderanalyze-promiseaxeresults)) and that will resolve a promise to the `await`

Comment: @StevenLambert I'm not quite sure if I get that correctly but I'm still getting the same output. Could you show me specifically on my example above what I have to change?

Comment: ```js
await driver.get('https://digital.hamburg.de/');
try {
  const results = new AxeBuilder(driver).analyze();
  console.log(results.violations);
} catch(err) {
  console.log("Something went wrong", e.message);
} finally {
  await driver.close()
}
```

Comment: @StevenLambert Thanks for your response. 
Unfortunately I'm still getting the same output.

Comment: If that didn't work, maybe try adding a `.catch` to the `main` function call: `main().catch(err => console.log(err))`. That's only thing I can think of that would cause the unhandled promise rejection